# Use an array to find a specific word in a string (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, include, match

I have an array called '**hello**' containing expressions

```
var hello = ['hi', 'hello', 'yo', 'hey', 'howdy'];
```

And a string stored in '**usertext**' that I get from the user.

I want to check if '**usertext**' is containing one of the expressions stored in '**hello**' and return *true/false*, '**usertext**' can contain a whole sentence.

So far I tried

```
if (usertext.includes(hello)) {
    var garfieldtext = "Hello. I'm Garfield, what's your name?";
}
```

I'm sorry if it has already been asked, I didn't find (or understand) the solution out there.

I'm very new to JS

Answer (score 0):

make use of JavaScript's `some` method. It returns `true` if any of the condition is met.

```js
const hello = ['hi', 'hello', 'yo', 'hey', 'howdy'];
const userText = "some text in here hello";

const helloExist = hello.some(item => userText.toLowerCase().includes(item));

if (helloExist) {
    console.log("Hello. I'm Garfield, what's your name?");
}
```

documentation for [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)